# My dwarves are getting lazy

Tags: dwarf-fortress

My dwarves are starting being lazy. How to know what's wrong with them (and cure it if there is a universally known reason for their laziness)?

EDIT: Sorry for my question being vague. I meant that there is still a number of unfinished tasks and many of my dwarves are idle doing nothing.

Comment: Seconding Raven Dreamer here, we need more details.

Comment: All seven of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dwarves aren't lazy. In fact, if they don't have something to do they'll get depressed. [Dwarf Therapist](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=66525.0) is great for keeping track of what labors you have assigned to what dwarves.
Did you just get a huge migration wave? The new dwarves will want to go to your meeting hall and talk to the other dwarves before they start working, so it may take a bit for that to get settled. If a dwarf is trapped somewhere (poorly thought out masonry is pretty common) he'll go idle until you free him.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little too vague as is, I think. Do you have a large number of idlers and tasks are still not being done? Have you scheduled "owned" items for dumping, only to find them not being moved? Is the area with the task unaccessible? Do your dwarves have the proper jobs enabled?

We need more of a description of what's not working before anyone can give a precise explanation.

Comment: Clarifications should be posted as comments, not answers, unless you have an accompanying answer amidst all the inquiries. Well, the question has since been edited to clarify some of the inquired points, so I suppose you're more likely to edit this into an appropriate answer than to convert it to a comment, at this point.

Comment: @Grace -- Every sentence other than the first and the last are possible solutions; without further input from the OP, it was a question of which one was *right*.

Comment: I suppose the phrasing is what throws me off. Your questions look more like attempts to figure what the problem is, the intent being to follow up with an explanation of what to do when, say, one has a large number of idlers yet tasks not being done. I don't play DF so I can't immediately tell that the questions are rhetorically answers. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Grace -- That's fair.